# How to connect kafka python client to k8s service?

Tags: python, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I have k8s Kafka services running at 10.zz.yy.xx on 9092 port. I have python client installed for kafka. So wanna try producer and consumer working fine or not.

here is `producer.py`

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
kafka_host = "10.zz.yy.xx.:9092"
print(kafka_host)

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_host)
 print("Initialized")
 producer.send('Hello','This is my text')


TOPIC_NAME = 'items'
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_host)
                          
producer.send(TOPIC_NAME, b'Test Message')
producer.flush()`
```

here is `consumer.py`

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
TOPIC_NAME = 'items'
consumer = KafkaConsumer(TOPIC_NAME)
for message in consumer:
    print(message)
```

I am getting error as : `kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable`.
Am i pointing to wrong services ? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You need to share how you installed Kafka into k8s. For example, are you using a port forward here or trying to connect to a single pod inside the cluster? Do you have any ingress or services that actually expose Kafka endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to connect to the Zookeper port, but rather to the Kafka Broker port.
Trying to connect to Zookeper will end up with
`kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable` error message.

As per [documentation](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html)

> bootstrap_servers – ‘host[:port]’ string (or list of ‘host[:port]’ strings) that the consumer should contact to bootstrap initial cluster metadata. This does not have to be the full node list. **It just needs to have at least one broker** that will respond to a Metadata API Request. Default port is 9092. If no servers are specified, will default to localhost:9092

Comment: Question is using 9092, not the Zookeeper port